# Who is Samyuka Barhaspatya?

Tags: rishi, yajna, shatapatha-brahmana, brihaspati

The **[Shatapatha Brahmana 1.9.1](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe12/sbe1237.htm)** mentions about a certain priest who went to heaven after performing a particular fire-sacrifice:

> 24. Thereupon he pronounces the 'All-hail and blessing' (sam-yos). **Now it was Samyu Bârhaspatya who perceived, in its true nature, the consummation of the sacrifice. He went to share in the world of the gods. Thereupon that (knowledge) was entirely lost to men.**
> 25. It then became known to the Rishis, that Samyu Bârhaspatya had perceived, in its true nature, the consummation of the sacrifice, and had gone to share in the world of the gods. By pronouncing the samyoh, they attained to that same consummation of the sacrifice which **Samyu Bârhaspatya had perceived; and to that same consummation of the sacrifice, which Samyu Bârhaspatya** had perceived, this (Hotri) attains by pronouncing the sam-yoh. For this reason he pronounces the 'All-hail and blessing.'
> 26. He intones, 'We long for that All-hail and blessing (sam-yoh);' whereby he says, 'We long for that consummation of the sacrifice which **Samyu Bârhaspatya** perceived.'

**I want to know who is this Samyu Bârhaspatya who achieved heaven by means of the sacrifice & what is his life story?** The only two sons of Brihaspati that come to my mind are Kacha and Bharadwaj so is he related to either of them or is a different descendant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Vayu Purana, Chapter 71](http://hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/vayu-mahapurana/text-with-translation/vol-ii/chapter-71), Shamyu was the son of Brihaspati who has inquired about Pitris and Shraddha to his father.

> सूत उवाच
>   एतद्वोऽहं प्रवक्ष्यामि पितृसर्गमनुत्तमम्। 
>   शंयुः पप्रच्छ यत्पूर्वं पितरं वै बृहस्पतिम्॥ ३७॥
>
> Sūte spoke-I shall talk of the most excellent creation of Pitaras. **What Samyu enquired earlier to his father Bṛhaspati**, this is the same question.
>
> बृहस्पतिमुपासीनं सर्वज्ञानार्थकोविदम्। 
>   पुनः शंयुरिमं प्रश्नं पप्रच्छ विनयान्वित:॥३८॥
>
> As Bṛhaspati, an expert in the import of all the learnings, was sitting closer, the son Samyu endowed with discipline, put this question.
>
> के एते पितरो नाम कियन्तः के च नामतः। 
>   समुद्भूताः कथं चैते पितृत्वं समुपागताः॥३९॥
>
> “Who are these Pitrs? What are their names? How these ones were born and how did they attain to the status of Pitaras?

Comment: Awesome find and quite timely too considering the Pitri Paksh is currently on :) Please do share anything else about him if possible I want to know more about his life and especially how he attained heaven. Also any idea if it is just another name of Kacha or Bharadwaj?

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal Thanks. But no idea about if Shamyu is same as either Kacha or Bharadvaja.

Comment: Hmmm I am surprised that no other scriptures mention this son of Brihaspati so possibly he is one of the two. Lets see if some other evidence turns up!